# Algoritmo de backtracking con condicional Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

Estoy intentado resolver un ejercicio que se me planteo que es bastante simple, dada una lista, imprimir todas las posibles combinaciones/permutaciones de x elementos. Es decir, sacar todas las combinaciones posibles pero dado un filtro para los resultados.

De momento tengo esto:

```
def permutation( list , start , end ):
    if (start == end ):
        print list
    else:
        for i in xrange(start , end + 1):
            list[start] , list[i] = list[i] , list[start]            
            permutation( list , start + 1 , end )
            list[start] , list[i] = list[i] , list[start] #Backtracking
```

Ejemplo: lista `[a,b,c]` de 2 elementos, resultado esperado `[a,b][a,c][b,a][b,c][c,a][c,b]`

Y otra duda que tengo es si hay alguna forma de hacerlo pero con repeticiones. Con el ejemplo anterior, el resultado deseado: `[a,b][a,c][b,a][b,c][c,a][c,b][a,a][b,b][c,c]`

En mi ejercicio propuesto la lista tiene 45 elementos y se piden las combinaciones de 20 elementos.

Comment: con repeticiones ten en cuenta que la longitud del `output` será de `len(permutation)^2`. y en cada iteracion `list[start]` añades uno que sea doble -> `aa`, `bb`, `cc`...

Comment: Con repetición es simple: `[[a,b] for a in lista for b in lista]`. Del resto, no entiendo el enunciado. ¿Qué son `start` y `end`?¿Qué filtros aplicas a los resultados?¿Dónde está el resultado que devuelve la función? Tampoco deberías modificar directamente la lista de entrada, es peligroso, ni usar `list` como nombre de variable.

Comment: Por favor aclara un poco tu problema, ¿a que te refieres con 'filtro'?, ¿cuál es el 'filtro'?, ¿las combinaciones son siempre de 2 elementos?, ¿que son los parámetros `start` y `end`?, etc. Tal y como está es difícil que te podamos ayudar. Si quieres combinaciones  de 2 elementos lo sencillo es usar list comprehensions como bién te indica Chema, para las permutaciones de 2 elementos  te añades un condicional `[[a, b] for a in lista for b in lista if a != b]`.

Answer (score 1):

Existe un módulo en la libería estándar, `itertools`, que implementa iteradores eficientes para muchos tipos de combinaciones.

```
from itertools import combinations, combinations_with_replacement

lista = [a, b, c]

# dos elementos, sin repetición
sin_repeticion = [x for x in combinations(lista, 2)]

# dos elementos, con repetición
con_repeticion = [x for x in combinations_with_replacement(lista, 2)]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

El filtro puedes establecerlo como un condicional en la list comprehension o en un bucle `for` sobre el iterador.

Answer (score 1):

Una manera muy sencilla de resolverlo sería simplemente usando list comprehension

```
mi_lista = [1,2,3,4]
# para los elementos con repeticiones, obtenemos una lista de tuplas
print [ (x,y) for x in mi_lista for y in mi_lista ]
# para los elementos sin repeticón solo agregamos la condición,
# para que los elementos x,y sean diferentes
print [ (x,y) for x in mi_lista for y in mi_lista if x!=y]
```